# Android : in-app Billing problem- getting the order Id from the response

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using In-App purchase in my application. I am successfully purchased the products. I am unable to get the order Id from the market response once the payment was made.anyone help me to retrieve the order ID from the response from the market. kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please mention your in app billing version what you are using in your question. check this link for v3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152065/in-app-billing-v3-error-in-activity-result/19158121#19158121

Answer (score 0):

`purchase.getSignature()`

I'm not sure this is what you're looking ,

but I use this to uniqe my order.

And this work fine for me.(With test account and signed APK)