# Android InApp Billing v3 cancel consumption

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, consumption

I have working app with in-app products (InApp billing v3).

Recently I've made an update for this app and made a terrible mistake there: I consumed some of purchases I didn't want to consume.

I issued an update and users updated the app and then wrote me they have no purchased access. (As I found later, I consumed wrong items).

So I have some questions now:

- Is there a way to restore consumed purchases or I should return payments to my users?
- Is there a way to find out how many and which purchases were consumed?
- If returning payments, is there a way to find out if user still has the product or is it consumed with out changing the app (through google services)?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Big G always keeps records of all the purchases. You will have to go through the Dev Guide for further information about the Implementation. http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

Comment: What I wished to ask: is there a way to request information about consumed products like about owned products.

Comment: it seems you haven't changed in the developer console product type, you just changed in the updated code in your app only. because Google console does not allow you to change product type after you create it. Let me know what you are exactly looking for.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I have understood from your question, It seems like you want to purchase product only once.

**What I wished to ask: is there a way to request information about consumed products like about owned products.**

you can get response or it's information in any type(Managed Product, Unmanaged Product, Subscription) in the onActivityResult method() check my below link.

> [In-app billing-v3 error in activity result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152065/in-app-billing-v3-error-in-activity-result/19158121#19158121)

but I would not prefer you to manage it customly as you told for one time purchase product(not consumable product). You should go with the Manage product.

**Managed In-app Products:**

> Managed in-app products are items that have their ownership
>   information tracked and managed by Google Play. When a user purchases
>   a managed in-app item, Google Play stores the purchase information for
>   each item on a per-user basis. This enables you to later query Google
>   Play at any time to restore the state of the items a specific user has
>   purchased. This information is persistent on the Google Play servers
>   even if the user uninstalls the application or if they change devices.

[for more information about product type](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#producttypes)

you can query any time you want and you will get the product information, and even you don't need to manage if user has already purchase this product or not.

**Is there a way to restore cnsumed purchases or I should return payments to my users?**

Better option is you should give the payments back to the user and for the next time check the whole app once using dummy product "android.test.purchased" and update your app.

**Is there a wat to find out how many and which purchases were consumed?**

You have to check in the Google wallet because all transaction should be handle by the it, check if it gives you product type or not. Using your google developer console credential you can signed into google wallet.

**If returning payments is there a way to find out if user stil has the product or is it consumed with out changing the app (through google services)?**

as per above answer you have to check in google wallet, according to my knowledge they are provide us all of information about product type with user detail.

Let me know if I have not properly understood your question.

Hope it will solve your problem.