# In-app Billing, Order History in Wallet

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay, android-billing

I have a lot of cancelled purchased. all, because the user didn't confirm his credit card.

I checked one of my successful purchased. There is a table that shows order history for this individual purchase/order.

> Oct 24    4:43 PM Charged The customer's credit card was successfully
>   charged for £6.50.
>
> Oct 24    4:43 PM Charging    You initiated a charge of £6.50 to the
>   customer's credit card.
>
> Oct 24    10:42 AM    Chargeable  The order was delivered.
>
> Oct 24    10:42 AM    Chargeable  The customer's credit card was authorized
>   for £6.50 and passed all risk checks. (Expires Oct 31, 2013 10:42:30
>   AM PDT).
>
> Oct 24    10:42 AM    Pending You received a new order. Google has sent the
>   customer an order confirmation email.

Google has sent the customer an order confirmation email.

Other cancelled orders only have the last msg and order get expired and then cancelled automatically. because user didn't confirm his credit card.

Question: in fail case. I don't really know if the customer managed to open my product. does my app receive a successful purchase or not?

Does `onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)` in `IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener()` get called with a successful purchase before customer confirmation for the order or credit card confirmation?

```
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
            setWaitScreen(false);
            return;
        }

        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            setWaitScreen(false);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(video.storeId)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Video owned now. go to download.");
            SharedPreferences.Editor spe = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(VideoHome.this).edit();
            spe.putInt(video.storeId, 1);
            spe.commit();
            videos.clear();
            loadVideos();
            videoClicked(video);
        }
    }
```

Comment: onIabPurchaseFinished listener will be called only when your item is successfully purchase. And if you know for the other cases like cancel purchase and other scenario then you can check it by onActivityResult(). check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152065/in-app-billing-v3-error-in-activity-result/19158121#19158121

Comment: you can get purchased information using getSkuDetail() method and using hasPurchase(SKU) method to verify whether this user has been purchased this item before accessing your purchased item. Let me know if you have still any queries.http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-requests and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658550/get-purchased-item-detail-at-start-of-app-with-iabhelper-android

Comment: It's less priority now. I have a lot of work on other projects. don't time to investigate this issue more. Thank you very much. I will get back to this later.