# get purchased item detail at start of app with IabHelper android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have implemented In-App in my application in that there is list of images with grid when user select image if user has already purchased that item it should never called again otherwise it should called method of

```
   mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
```

i have successfully integrate in-app with my app and also item is being purchased but i want to know at start up if that item is purchased or not if not purchased than above code should be called otherwise it should allow to download that image

Comment: have you tried getPurchase() method? check this link: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-requests (Querying for Purchased Items) 

Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
Let me know if it will not be helpful for you.

Comment: you can check it by using unique product id declare in the developer console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally i found solution of how to get information of purchased item if it is already purchased or not

```
    // subscriptions we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
            Inventory inventory) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        mIsPremium = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM); ------> By here you can get information 

    }
};
```

Comment: Dude if this answer helped you then please consider accepting the answer so that other users can know that this answer is the solution.

Comment: for me Pruchase.getOrderId() returning empty string...any suggestion why !

Comment: How can I get list of All the purchased Items so far ?